# fstream issue under 64-bits cygwin

Tags: c++, cygwin, mingw32

I don't like working under Cygwin actually.

The problem is when I use 64-bits g++ to compile the same piece of code, I get unexpected different result.

The source code looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int rows = 200;
    int cols = 200;
    float data[rows*cols];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            data[i*cols+j] = i*cols+j;
        }
    }
    const char *file = "tmp.txt";
    ofstream fs(file);
    if (fs.is_open())
    {
        fs.write((char*)&rows, sizeof(int));
        cout << fs.tellp() << endl;
        fs.write((char*)&cols, sizeof(int));
        cout << fs.tellp() << endl;
        fs.write((char*)data, sizeof(float)*rows*cols);
        cout << fs.tellp() << endl;
        fs.close();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am writing two integers and a block of float values into a binary file.
It prints out how many bytes it wrote.

The expected result is:

```
4
8
160008
```

All the actions were performed under Cygwin.
When the code was compiled with g++.exe, the result is right.

But when I use x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe (only by which can generate 64-bits binary), the result is wired.

```
4
8
160506
```

It is wired, what extra bytes for?
I am trying my luck here.

Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that because the file is not opened in binary mode, every newline character (i.e., 0x0A byte) is being converted to a carriage-return+newline sequence.  And I bet there just happen to be 500 such bytes in your array of floats.

Try opening your output stream like this:

```
ofstream fs(file, ios_base::binary);
```

Comment: You can simplify the code a bit: `std::ios_base::out` is added automatically for `std::ofstream` i.e. `std::ofstream out(filename, std::ios_base::binary)` should suffice. It is a bit weird though that a 32 bit version behaves differently: it would mean the file is internally always openen in binary mode for 32 bit mode (which would closely mimick UNIX behavior) but not in 64 bit mode.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Nemo! Problem is solved by adding ios_base::binary. But I don't have newline character in my data, how ofstream can decide there is a newline or not?

Comment: @mr.pppoe - Your `float` array is binary data; i.e., just a bunch of bytes.  Somewhere in there, some of those bytes are likely to equal 0x0A, which is a newline.

Comment: @Nemo This do make sense. When I change the value in the float array, the number of extra bytes change too, thanks much!